# is there an easy way to access the code put into a slot from the child in vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, pre

I'm trying to create this component library with code examples on how to use my components.

I've made this 'preview' component which just renders the $slot.default as a component, below the component I also want to render a code block with the code that i've put into the slot. Is there a simple way to access the original slot code aswell? Next to this already processed vnode object I can access.

preview.comp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <pre v-html="$slots.default[0]"></pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

parent.comp.vue

```
<preview>
  <a-button state="primary">Button</a-button>
</preview>
```

Comment: If you use v-html directive to say this is html interpreted, if you simply output the html without that directive, the browser will print the html in screen without interpreting it: `<div>{{ $slots.default[0] }}</div>`

Comment: But that targets the processed component, which is a `vnode` object. I'm trying to get the actual html that i'm putting into it like `<a-button state="primary">Button</a-button>`